# cocos2d-x: can not create callback from onContactBegin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x, collision-detection, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have problem with collisions. 
I use VS 2013 Community Edition and I create onContactBegin function like this:

```
bool GameScene::onContactBegin(cocos2d::PhysicsContact &contact)
{
    PhysicsBody* bodyA = contact.getShapeA()->getBody();
    PhysicsBody* bodyB = contact.getShapeB()->getBody();
    return true;
}
```

but when I try to create contact listener:

```
auto contactListener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
contactListener->onContactBegin = CC_CALLBACK_1(GameScene::onContactBegin, this);
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(contactListener, this);
```

my precompiler starts to cry on CC_CALLBACK_1 function:

no instance of overloaded function std::bind matches the argument list

Any help?

Comment: I think that should work; but try with `onContactBegin(const cocos2d::PhysicsContact &contact)`.  Also have you *declared* the `onContactBegin` method in the header file?

Comment: Thanks, 
my fold was that I have declared two onContactBegin methods.